# Sharepoint Foundation 2010 - Site structure for our implementation

Tags: permissions

I have been tasked with implementing document control for my organisation. The structure is roughly:

**Department 1**
- Contract 1
- Contract 2
- Contract 3

**Department 2**
- Contract 1
- Contract 2
- Contract 3

In regards to Sharepoint sites, am I right in saying that I should implement a site per department then subsites for each contract within each department?

I feel there may be some better, 'built-in' way of building this very typical company stucture. Assigning permissions in particular seems a bit of a headache with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, breaking departments down into subsites will make security much more easier, giving you better control.

As for having the contracts as subsites, that would depend on your security requirements - if you need to strictly control security between contracts then I would also make those subsites.

regards,
KS